# How to Improve the Layout of a Credits Table

Tags: website-design, layout, tables, purchase

I have this table which enables users to see different credit packs, and give the option to go ahead an purchase one. However I feel it is not as effective as it could be and I want to try to increase the conversion within it.

[image]

I am fully open to changing in it whatever way, my specific questions though are:

- What is the right way to list credit packs such as this in terms of price, call-to-action and value for the easiest UX
- Any tips on how can I make this visually more effective for the user?
- Does having the words "Buy With PayPal" repeated have any negative indications should it simply be purchase
- Would it be beneficial from a user stand point to try and visually show the differnt size of the credit packs?
- Lastly: My prices are in GBP£ however is using the term GBP £ confusing, should it be £ or GBP or as it is?

**UPDATE**

Based on the feedback I thought I would make something far more visual:
 - Do you think the diagram is clear enough in protraying the different credit values?
 - Which icon do you think it clearer as to the engaging the user?
 - Is it better?!
 - Is the fact it is so different bad for the user? Or does it not matter?

[image]

Comment: It's usual to see the cost per credit at each price point, so the user can see the value in bulk-buying. However that might expose that there is no benefit (at least with the prices you've posted).

Comment: Also, the pie chart you'd added is absolutely the wrong one to use. Each pack isn't a part of a whole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pricing plan looks a little boring and not visual appealing. Moreover, it's non-informative and non-persuasive.

[7 Useful Design Strategies for a Successful Pricing Table](http://uxmovement.com/content/7-useful-design-strategies-for-a-successful-pricing-table/) describes some techniques, which allow to get better design. Some ideas are:

- focus on the benefits and features of each plan
- decoy to deflect focus off your highest pricing plan
- highlight the middle plan

An example of modern pricing table:
[image]

.

**UPDATE**
If there is no any information which could be used in conjunction with each option to convince users, than you could turn to opposite side: use clear minimalistic design.
[image]

Comment: I've done something more graphical as you can see in the update - do you think this is better?

Comment: @tim.baker, please watch upgrade section. The blue circle in your new design doesn't look connected with right side.

Answer (score 3):

My comments:

- Consider changing *cost* to *price* (the former may have a more negative tone).
- No need for the GBP/£ duality - £ is more universal than GBP, so use £.
- Not sure why using *Number of Credits (Texts)* instead of simply *Number of Texts*.
- No need for the Buy with paypal duality. Just use 'Buy' and put under the table something like 'payments are taken using paypal'.
- Buy button should be call for action - so bright colour and make it look like a button.
- The pricing is somewhat not attractive, for instance, its cheaper to buy 2x340 (=680) than buying 1x670. Make users feel they save if they buy for more, and make it easy to work out.
- Why purple?

Something like this:

[image: A pricing table]

Comment: Thanks, the pricing structure isn't my decision... The purple is a hangover from previous designs, not sure how to change it while it keep it similar to those designs, something else I have been trying to workout for sometime. I like what you said about the £ and language of Price!

Comment: I've taken your feedback and updated it, be good to see what you make of it!